# How do I add an attribute in admin Catalog -> Manage Products

Tags: attributes, ce-1.6.2.0

I added an attribute to use with a shipping restriction (I marked the attribute to be used with Promo rules for this) and the attribute behaves as it should, but I have no way of manually editing the attribute.  Under the admin `Catalog -> Manage Products` I'd like to add a selection box to be able to set the attribute.  How would I go about doing this in Magento CE 1.6.2.0?

Comment: After setting up the attribute, did you add it to your Attribute-Set?

Comment: @StefanGregori That is one piece I was missing...I just dragged it to the default group and saved the set.  It still isn't showing up in `Manage Products` though

Comment: Reindex all the data under Index-Management and if dropdown, select or multiselect check if you have added options to your attribute that actually can be selected

Comment: @StefanGregori I reindexed everything, and the input type is `Yes/No`.  Should I re-create the attribute with another input type, maybe "Dropdown"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @StefanGregori and this page http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/39002/ I found my problem.

Adding the attribute to the "Default" Attribute Set will only show that attribute for products that have the "Default" Attribute Set.  If you have a different, custom Attribute Set, you will also need to add the attribute to that Set for it to show up in "Manage Products" for products with that Attribute Set.

In my case, I had "Default" as one attribute set (and no products were associated with it) and a custom Attribute Set that all products were associated with.

Comment: sure, i thought this is clear ;)